# Find the first occurence of a value in a map in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to find the first occurence of a value in a map in Java and change it using lambda expression. How can I achieve using Stream API?

Below is the code using iterator.

```
Map<String, String> details = new LinkedHashMap<>();

Iterator<Entry<String, String>> entries = details.entrySet().iterator();
 while(entries.hasNext()){
     Map.Entry<String, String> entry = entries.next();
     if(Status.PENDING.equals(entry.getValue())) {
         details.put(entry.getKey(), Status.FAILED);
         break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question here. I suppose you want to do it with the Stream API? Why, and where are you stuck?

Comment: OK, but is there somewhere you're stuck? Have you taken the [stream tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/)?

Answer (score 1):

Achieved it as follows:

```
String matchingKey = details.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(Status.PENDING)).map(Map.Entry::getKey).findFirst().orElse(null);
details.put(matchingKey, Status.FAILED);
```

Comment: No need for `map`; you can just do `setValue` on the entry.

Comment: `details.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(Status.PENDING)) .findFirst().ifPresent(entry -> entry.setValue(Status.FAILED));`

Comment: Note that what @tobias_k said, also applies to the loop variant; there is no need to perform another key lookup when you already have the `Entry`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of your `Map`, then [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) it somehow and then [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) the result.